# input data bring data from 'A' table then check with 'B' table with the data then show the data when the data not in 'B' table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have two table. first table name is A, second table name is B. then compare the two table with input data. input data bring data from 'A' table then check with 'B' table with the data then show the data when the data not in 'B' table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine both tables using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableA a 
        LEFT JOIN tableB b
            ON a.colName = b.colName
WHERE   b.colName IS NULL
```

`colname` is the column that defines the relationship between the two tables.

Comment: but one condition, the checking data in both table is same but result data different from A table. so how can i add this one in your query

Comment: can you do me a favor? can you include samplr data on your question and the desired result? that way we can easily understand what you really want :D